# Replace content of comment-directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm stuck with dynamic template for a directive. Mainly, the directive that called as a comment.

For example, I have created a directive that should check the type of element and an appropriate template. In the link-function I check attribute type of element in the scope and select required template.

All works fine if I call directive as an attribute or an element. However, if I call it as a comment then nothing happens, the output is empty.

Here the code of that directive:

```
app.directive('inQux', function ($compile) {
    var template, inQux, linker;

    template = {
        foo: '<div>I\'m foo. {{item.value}}</div>',
        bar: '<div>I\'m bar. {{item.value}}</div>'
    };


    linker = function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        var content = $compile(template[$scope.item.type])($scope);

        element.append(content);
    };

    inQux = {
        restrict: 'AME',
        replace: true,
        link: linker
    };

    return inQux;
});
```

You can find full example by following [the link](http://jsfiddle.net/VanSanblch/Qsf92/)

So, my question is there a way to replace content for comment-directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't use element.append() within the link function of a directive in case of directives as comments. But the explanation is simple: appending elements to comment nodes isn't possible.

If you use another approach (binding the template directly to your directive) like this:

```
app.directive('inQux', function ($compile) {
    var inQux;

    inQux = {
        template: '<div>I\'m {{item.type}}. {{item.value}}</div>',
        restrict: 'AME',
        replace: true
    };

    return inQux;
});
```

... and like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lutze/Qsf92/3/) it works. As additional advantage the code of the directive is much smaller now ... but I don't know what do you want to achieve in your original app.

Comment: Yes, looks if I add template-attribute then everything works almost fine.

    element.html(template[$scope.item.type]);
    $compile(element.contents())($scope);

Actually, code example on jsfiddle is a great simplification of real production code. What I need is change template that directive should use on a specific value in its scope.

Comment: A possible way is to use the `ng-switch` directive within the template like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lutze/Qsf92/4/).